# PHP Object++ (int ++)

Tags: php, object, integer

Is it possible to do object++ in php?

I'am just wondering if something like this is possible, if so how would I achive something like this?

Example:

```
class x
{
    private $data = 0;
}

$a = new x();
$a++;
```

Comment: Run a duplicate instance of x()?

Comment: How do you think `PHP` will be able to understand what to increase in your object? (try `include "read_mind.php"`)

Comment: You can't increment object, instant of that  you can use operator overloading to create the instance of one object and runt his as duplicate instance of your x(). may be in this way we can do this.

Comment: @Code_Crash I'am curious about what you are saying can you give an example?

Comment: According to manual (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php): `The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and strings. Arrays, objects and resources are not affected`

Comment: @WhiteFang I'm curious on the use-case of incrementing an object

Comment: @Code_Crash PHP doesn't allow `operator overloading`. Most likely you confuse it with `C/C++`

Comment: yup right @hindmost. I done this in c++ before 2 year ago so now i don't know it work in php or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not overwrite ++ and -- (nor any other) operator in PHP, unlike C++ or Ruby for example, if that is the question.

Comment: That's indeed what I wanted, It would be nice if PHP had this :)

Comment: You could say PHP is not the most expressive programming language but hey, on the other hand it's often not obvious what you are doing by overloading operators anyway - I personally would never implement the thing you asked by operator overloading.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are trying to increase the variable $data inside the class x?

If so, you will want to do something like this:

```
class x
{
    private $data = 0;

    public function increaseData()
    {
         $this->data++;
    }
}

$a = new x();
$a->increaseData();
```

Comment: Yes I know this just wondering if I could use a shorthand like ++ for oop style.

Comment: Then im afraid not, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the `private` members from outside of the class , However you can increment a `public` variable outside of your class.

```
<?php
class x
{
    private $data = 0;
    public $newdata = 0;

}

$a = new x();
$a->newdata++;
var_dump($a);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
object(x)[1]
  private 'data' => int 0
  public 'newdata' => int 1
```

---

#### An ugly hack using Reflections... (Modifying private variables outside)

Using Reflections you can even modify the private properties outside , but this breaks the OOP paradigm , so don't do it. This is just for your understanding..

```
<?php
class x
{
    public $newdata = 0;
    private $data = 0;

}


$a = new x();
var_dump($a);
# Incrementing public var
$a->newdata++;

# Setting the private var
$b = new ReflectionProperty(get_class($a), 'data');
$b->setAccessible(true);
$b->setValue($a, $b->getValue($a)+1);
var_dump($a);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
class x#1 (2) {
  private $data =>
  int(0)
  public $newdata =>
  int(0)
}
class x#1 (2) {
  private $data =>
  int(1)
  public $newdata =>
  int(1)
}
```